# insert null values in missing rows of file

Tags: perl, date, datetime, awk

I have a text file which consists some data of 24 hours time stamp segregated in 10 minutes interval.

```
2016-02-06,00:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1  
2016-02-06,00:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1  
2016-02-06,00:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1  
2016-02-06,00:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1  
2016-02-06,00:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,42,0,2  
2016-02-06,01:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,55,0,2  
2016-02-06,01:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,41,0,2  
2016-02-06,01:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,46,0,2  
2016-02-06,01:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,56,0,3  
2016-02-06,01:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,38,0,2  
2016-02-06,01:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,49,0,2  
2016-02-06,02:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,58,0,4  
2016-02-06,02:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,43,0,2  
2016-02-06,02:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,46,0,2  
2016-02-06,02:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,61,0,2  
2016-02-06,02:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,57,0,3  
2016-02-06,02:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,45,0,2  
2016-02-06,03:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,45,0,3  
2016-02-06,03:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,51,0,2  
2016-02-06,03:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,68,0,3  
2016-02-06,03:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,51,0,2  
2016-02-06,03:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,68,0,3  
2016-02-06,03:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,67,0,3  
2016-02-06,04:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,82,0,8  
2016-02-06,04:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,82,0,5  
2016-02-06,04:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,122,0,4   
2016-02-06,04:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,133,0,3  
2016-02-06,04:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,142,0,3  
2016-02-06,04:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,202,0,1  
2016-02-06,05:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,731,1,3  
2016-02-06,05:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,372,0,7  
2016-02-06,05:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,303,0,2  
2016-02-06,05:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,389,0,3  
2016-02-06,05:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,454,0,1  
2016-02-06,05:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,406,0,6  
2016-02-06,06:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,377,0,1  
2016-02-06,06:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,343,0,5  
2016-02-06,06:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,370,0,2  
2016-02-06,06:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,343,0,9  
2016-02-06,06:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,315,0,8  
2016-02-06,06:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,458,0,3  
2016-02-06,07:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,756,1,3  
2016-02-06,07:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,913,1,3  
2016-02-06,07:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,522,0,3  
2016-02-06,07:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,350,0,7  
2016-02-06,07:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,328,0,6  
2016-02-06,07:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,775,1,3  
2016-02-06,08:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,310,0,9  
2016-02-06,08:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,308,0,6  
2016-02-06,08:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,738,1,3  
2016-02-06,08:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,294,0,6  
2016-02-06,08:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,345,0,1  
2016-02-06,08:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,367,0,6  
2016-02-06,09:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,480,0,3  
2016-02-06,09:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,390,0,3  
2016-02-06,09:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,436,0,3  
2016-02-06,09:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1404,2,3  
2016-02-06,09:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,346,0,3  
2016-02-06,09:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,388,0,3  
2016-02-06,10:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,456,0,2  
2016-02-06,10:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,273,0,7  
2016-02-06,10:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,310,0,3  
2016-02-06,10:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,256,0,7  
2016-02-06,10:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,283,0,3  
2016-02-06,10:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,276,0,3  
2016-02-06,11:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,305,0,1  
2016-02-06,11:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,310,0,9  
2016-02-06,11:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,286,0,3  
2016-02-06,11:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,286,0,3  
2016-02-06,11:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,247,0,7  
2016-02-06,11:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,366,0,2  
2016-02-06,12:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,294,0,2  
2016-02-06,12:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,216,0,5  
2016-02-06,12:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,233,0,1  
2016-02-06,12:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,785,1,2  
2016-02-06,12:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,466,0,1  
2016-02-06,12:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,219,0,9  
2016-02-06,13:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,248,0,6  
2016-02-06,13:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,223,0,7  
2016-02-06,13:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,276,0,8  
2016-02-06,13:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,219,0,6  
2016-02-06,13:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,699,1,2  
2016-02-06,13:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,439,0,2  
2016-02-06,14:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1752,2,3  
2016-02-06,14:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,203,0,5  
2016-02-06,14:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,230,0,7  
2016-02-06,14:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,226,0,1  
2016-02-06,14:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,195,0,6  
2016-02-06,14:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,314,0,1  
2016-02-06,15:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,357,0,2  
2016-02-06,15:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,387,0,9  
2016-02-06,15:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1084,1,3  
2016-02-06,15:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1295,2,3  
2016-02-06,15:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,223,0,8  
2016-02-06,15:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,254,0,1  
2016-02-06,16:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,252,0,7  
2016-02-06,16:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,268,0,1  
2016-02-06,16:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,242,0,1  
2016-02-06,16:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,254,0,9  
2016-02-06,16:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,271,0,3  
2016-02-06,16:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,244,0,7  
2016-02-06,17:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,281,0,1  
2016-02-06,17:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,190,0,8  
2016-02-06,17:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,187,0,1  
2016-02-06,17:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,173,0,9  
2016-02-06,17:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,140,0,5  
2016-02-06,17:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,147,0,6  
2016-02-06,18:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,109,0,4  
2016-02-06,18:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,99,0,1  
2016-02-06,18:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,66,0,6  
2016-02-06,18:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,67,0,4  
2016-02-06,18:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,40,0,2  
2016-02-06,18:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,52,0,3  
2016-02-06,19:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,40,0,3  
2016-02-06,19:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,30,0,2  
2016-02-06,19:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,25,0,3  
2016-02-06,19:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,35,0,4  
2016-02-06,19:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,14,0,1  
2016-02-06,19:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,97,0,7  
2016-02-06,20:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,14,0,1  
2016-02-06,20:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,12,0,4  
2016-02-06,20:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,11,0,2  
2016-02-06,20:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,12,0,1  
2016-02-06,20:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,6,0,1   
2016-02-06,20:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,13,0,2  
2016-02-06,21:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,5,0,1   
2016-02-06,21:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,12,0,2  
2016-02-06,21:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1,0,1   
2016-02-06,21:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,21,0,2  
2016-02-06,21:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,9,0,3   
2016-02-06,22:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,2,0,1   
2016-02-06,22:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,12,0,5  
2016-02-06,22:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1,0,1   
2016-02-06,22:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,9,0,1   
2016-02-06,22:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,13,0,1  
2016-02-06,23:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,20,0,2  
2016-02-06,23:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,10,0,3  
2016-02-06,23:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,10,0,1  
2016-02-06,23:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,6,0,1   
2016-02-06,23:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,12,0,1
```

if you see above sample as per 10 minutes interval there should be total 143 rows in 24 hours in this file but after second last line which has time `2016-02-06,23:40:00` data for date, time `2016-02-06,23:50:00` is missing.

similarly after `2016-02-06,22:40:00` data for date, time `2016-02-06,22:50:00` is missing.

can we insert missing date,time followed by 6 null separated by commas e.g.  `2016-02-06,22:50:00,null,null,null,null,null,null` where ever any data missing in rows of this file based on count no 143 rows and time stamp comparison in rows `2016-02-06,00:00:00` to `2016-02-06,23:50:00` which is also 143 in count ?

here is what i have tried
created a file with 143 entries of date and time as 2.csv and used below command

```
join -j 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,2.1,2.1,2.2 <(sort -k2 1.csv) <(sort -k2 2.csv)|grep "2016-02-06,21:30:00"| sort -u|sed "s/\t//g"> 3.txt
```

part of output is repetitive like this :

```
        2016-02-06,21:30:00  
 2016-02-06,21:30:00  

2016-02-06,00:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1  
        2016-02-06,21:30:00  
 2016-02-06,21:30:00  

2016-02-06,00:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1  
        2016-02-06,21:30:00  
 2016-02-06,21:30:00  

2016-02-06,00:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1  
        2016-02-06,21:30:00  
 2016-02-06,21:30:00  

2016-02-06,00:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1  
        2016-02-06,21:30:00  
 2016-02-06,21:30:00  

2016-02-06,00:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,42,0,2  
        2016-02-06,21:30:00
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Well, yes, in a number of ways.  Which way are you approaching it -- can you show what part of it is not working?  Or do you not know how to go at it at all?

Comment: you are right, I know how to replace a missing word or blank space with null but no idea how to compare and insert null based on date and time stamp...could you please help ? this has become a road block in my reporting database and due to this populated charts are showing wrong data.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I just think that it would be good that you give us something that you are trying to work with.  Also, I'd suggest that you edit the question -- it is good that you are showing input but don't need to show all lines.

Comment: OK! please see what i tried. Edited in question. all my attempt is doing is to compare both files and printing a merge output but i see that its repeatedly printing missing date and time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another Perl solution

It initialises `$date` to the date contained in the first line of the file, and a time of `00:00:00`

It then fills the `%values` hash with records using the value of `$date` as a key, incrementing the value by ten minutes until the day of month changes. These form the "default" values

Then the contents of the file are used to overwrite all elements of `%values` for which we have an actual value. Any gaps will remain set to their default from the previous step

Then the hash is simply printed in sorted order, resulting in a full set of data with defaults inserted as necessary

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_MINUTE';
use Fcntl ':seek';

my $delta = 10 * ONE_MINUTE;

my $date = Time::Piece->strptime(<ARGV> =~ /^([\d-]+)/, '%Y-%m-%d');

my %values;

for ( my $day = $date->mday; $date->mday == $day; $date += $delta ) {
    my $ds = $date->strftime('%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S');
    $values{$ds} = $ds. ',null' x 6 . "\n";
}

seek ARGV, 0, SEEK_SET;
while ( <ARGV> ) {
    my ($ds) = /^([\d-]+,[\d:]+)/;
    $values{$ds} = $_;
}

print $values{$_} for sort keys %values;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually *not* cross reference a new csv file, and instead do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece; 

my $last_timestamp; 
my $interval = 600; 

#read stdin line by line
while ( <> ) {
   #extract date and time from this line. 
   my ( $date, $time, @fields ) = split /,/; 
   #parse the timestamp
   my $timestamp = Time::Piece -> strptime ( $date . $time, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S" );
   #set last if undefined. 
   $last_timestamp //= $timestamp; 
   #if there's a gap... :
   if (  $last_timestamp + $interval <  $timestamp ) { 
       #print "GAP detected at $timestamp: ",$timestamp - $last_timestamp,"\n";
       #print lines to fill in the gap
       for ( ($timestamp - $last_timestamp) % 600 ) { 
           $last_timestamp += 600;
           print join ( ",", $last_timestamp -> strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S"),  ("null")x6),"\n";
       }
   }
   $last_timestamp = $timestamp;
   print;
}
```

Which for your sample gives me lines (snipped for brevity):

```
2016-02-06,22:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,13,0,1
2016-02-06,22:50:00,null,null,null,null,null,null
2016-02-06,23:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,20,0,2
```

Note - this is assuming the timestamps are exactly 600s apart. You can adjust the logic a little if that isn't a valid assumption, but it depends exactly what you're trying to get at that point.

Comment: Like my original solution, this doesn't add a line for `2016-02-06,23:50:00` at the end

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer..

cat 1.csv 2.csv|sort -u -t, -k2,2

Comment: This sort may not be stable, so you have no guarantee that the first of an equal pair is from the first file, 1.csv. No need to cat and sort, use merge: `sort -t, -m -u -k2,2 stamps.dat stamps2.dat`

Answer (score 0):

...or a shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -e

file=$1
today=$(head -1 $file | cut -d, -f1)

line=0
for (( h = 0 ; h < 24 ; h++ ))
do
  for (( m = 0 ; m < 60 ; m += 10 ))
  do
    stamp=$(printf "%02d:%02d:00" $h $m)
    if [ $line -eq 0 ]; then IFS=',' read date time data; fi
    if [ "$time" = "$stamp" ]; then
      echo $date,$time,$data
      line=0
    else
      echo $today,$stamp,null,null,null,null,null,null
      line=1
    fi
  done
done <$file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this in Perl

This program expects the name of the input file as a parameter on the command line, and prints its output to STDOUT, which may be redirected as normal

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_MINUTE';

my $format = '%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S';
my $delta = 10 * ONE_MINUTE;

my $next;

our @ARGV = 'mydates.txt';

while ( <> ) {

    my $new = Time::Piece->strptime(/^([\d-]+,[\d:]+)/, $format);

    while ( $next and $next < $new ) {
        say $next->strftime($format) . ',null' x 6;
        $next += $delta;
    }

    print;

    $next = $new + $delta;
}

while ( $next and $next->hms('') > 0 ) {
    say $next->strftime($format) . ',null' x 6;
    $next += $delta;
}
```

#### output

```
2016-02-06,00:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1
2016-02-06,00:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1
2016-02-06,00:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1
2016-02-06,00:30:00,null,null,null,null,null,null
2016-02-06,00:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,37,0,1
2016-02-06,00:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,42,0,2
2016-02-06,01:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,55,0,2
2016-02-06,01:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,41,0,2
2016-02-06,01:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,46,0,2
2016-02-06,01:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,56,0,3
2016-02-06,01:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,38,0,2
2016-02-06,01:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,49,0,2
2016-02-06,02:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,58,0,4
2016-02-06,02:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,43,0,2
2016-02-06,02:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,46,0,2
2016-02-06,02:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,61,0,2
2016-02-06,02:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,57,0,3
2016-02-06,02:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,45,0,2
2016-02-06,03:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,45,0,3
2016-02-06,03:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,51,0,2
2016-02-06,03:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,68,0,3
2016-02-06,03:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,51,0,2
2016-02-06,03:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,68,0,3
2016-02-06,03:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,67,0,3
2016-02-06,04:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,82,0,8
2016-02-06,04:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,82,0,5
2016-02-06,04:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,122,0,4
2016-02-06,04:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,133,0,3
2016-02-06,04:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,142,0,3
2016-02-06,04:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,202,0,1
2016-02-06,05:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,731,1,3
2016-02-06,05:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,372,0,7
2016-02-06,05:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,303,0,2
2016-02-06,05:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,389,0,3
2016-02-06,05:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,454,0,1
2016-02-06,05:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,406,0,6
2016-02-06,06:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,377,0,1
2016-02-06,06:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,343,0,5
2016-02-06,06:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,370,0,2
2016-02-06,06:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,343,0,9
2016-02-06,06:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,315,0,8
2016-02-06,06:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,458,0,3
2016-02-06,07:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,756,1,3
2016-02-06,07:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,913,1,3
2016-02-06,07:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,522,0,3
2016-02-06,07:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,350,0,7
2016-02-06,07:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,328,0,6
2016-02-06,07:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,775,1,3
2016-02-06,08:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,310,0,9
2016-02-06,08:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,308,0,6
2016-02-06,08:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,738,1,3
2016-02-06,08:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,294,0,6
2016-02-06,08:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,345,0,1
2016-02-06,08:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,367,0,6
2016-02-06,09:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,480,0,3
2016-02-06,09:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,390,0,3
2016-02-06,09:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,436,0,3
2016-02-06,09:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1404,2,3
2016-02-06,09:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,346,0,3
2016-02-06,09:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,388,0,3
2016-02-06,10:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,456,0,2
2016-02-06,10:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,273,0,7
2016-02-06,10:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,310,0,3
2016-02-06,10:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,256,0,7
2016-02-06,10:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,283,0,3
2016-02-06,10:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,276,0,3
2016-02-06,11:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,305,0,1
2016-02-06,11:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,310,0,9
2016-02-06,11:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,286,0,3
2016-02-06,11:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,286,0,3
2016-02-06,11:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,247,0,7
2016-02-06,11:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,366,0,2
2016-02-06,12:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,294,0,2
2016-02-06,12:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,216,0,5
2016-02-06,12:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,233,0,1
2016-02-06,12:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,785,1,2
2016-02-06,12:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,466,0,1
2016-02-06,12:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,219,0,9
2016-02-06,13:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,248,0,6
2016-02-06,13:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,223,0,7
2016-02-06,13:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,276,0,8
2016-02-06,13:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,219,0,6
2016-02-06,13:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,699,1,2
2016-02-06,13:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,439,0,2
2016-02-06,14:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1752,2,3
2016-02-06,14:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,203,0,5
2016-02-06,14:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,230,0,7
2016-02-06,14:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,226,0,1
2016-02-06,14:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,195,0,6
2016-02-06,14:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,314,0,1
2016-02-06,15:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,357,0,2
2016-02-06,15:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,387,0,9
2016-02-06,15:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1084,1,3
2016-02-06,15:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1295,2,3
2016-02-06,15:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,223,0,8
2016-02-06,15:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,254,0,1
2016-02-06,16:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,252,0,7
2016-02-06,16:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,268,0,1
2016-02-06,16:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,242,0,1
2016-02-06,16:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,254,0,9
2016-02-06,16:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,271,0,3
2016-02-06,16:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,244,0,7
2016-02-06,17:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,281,0,1
2016-02-06,17:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,190,0,8
2016-02-06,17:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,187,0,1
2016-02-06,17:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,173,0,9
2016-02-06,17:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,140,0,5
2016-02-06,17:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,147,0,6
2016-02-06,18:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,109,0,4
2016-02-06,18:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,99,0,1
2016-02-06,18:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,66,0,6
2016-02-06,18:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,67,0,4
2016-02-06,18:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,40,0,2
2016-02-06,18:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,52,0,3
2016-02-06,19:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,40,0,3
2016-02-06,19:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,30,0,2
2016-02-06,19:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,25,0,3
2016-02-06,19:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,35,0,4
2016-02-06,19:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,14,0,1
2016-02-06,19:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,97,0,7
2016-02-06,20:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,14,0,1
2016-02-06,20:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,12,0,4
2016-02-06,20:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,11,0,2
2016-02-06,20:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,12,0,1
2016-02-06,20:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,6,0,1
2016-02-06,20:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,13,0,2
2016-02-06,21:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,5,0,1
2016-02-06,21:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,12,0,2
2016-02-06,21:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1,0,1
2016-02-06,21:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,21,0,2
2016-02-06,21:40:00,null,null,null,null,null,null
2016-02-06,21:50:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,9,0,3
2016-02-06,22:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,2,0,1
2016-02-06,22:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,12,0,5
2016-02-06,22:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,1,0,1
2016-02-06,22:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,9,0,1
2016-02-06,22:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,13,0,1
2016-02-06,22:50:00,null,null,null,null,null,null
2016-02-06,23:00:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,20,0,2
2016-02-06,23:10:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,10,0,3
2016-02-06,23:20:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,10,0,1
2016-02-06,23:30:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,6,0,1
2016-02-06,23:40:00,ujjawal,36072-2,MT,12,0,1
2016-02-06,23:50:00,null,null,null,null,null,null
```